# Node with higher ID always losing arbitration in CAN Bus

Tags: can-bus

I am a beginner in CAN Protocol, referring Texas Instruments Application Report SLOA101B - Introduction to the Controller Area Network (CAN).

What happens when 2 nodes are continuously sending CAN frames, will the node sending the frame higher CAN ID always lose arbitration?

In my understanding, in the initial arbitration, the node with lower ID wins, then sends the data frame, after which the bus goes to 3 recessive IFS, then again both nodes finds the bus as idle and starts arbitration, here also the node with lower ID wins the arbitration and so on. This means the node sending the frame higher CAN ID always loses arbitration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is correct. But apart from identifier, arbitration also involves the RTR/SRR bit as well as the IDE (extended identifier) bits. So an 11 bit frame with identifier 0x123 always wins over an 29 bit frame with identifier 0x123.

Though note that continuous, 100% bus load often means there is something seriously wrong with the bus.

Comment: Understood, so we should take care of the tx timing (when each frame is to be sent by different nodes) in the application layer, right?